# Unity3d. Google Play service problems. DEBUG: Authentication failed - developer error

Tags: unity-game-engine

Good people, I ran into a problem that stalled me for as long as a week. In general, the matter is this: I decided to be listed to connect to the game Google Service. It seems that I set everything up, and entered all the codes correctly. OAuth2 configured. I launch: The game starts, after a second it freezes and the screen darkens (you can see that there is an attempt to connect), it hangs and nothing. Nothing at all. I ran it through Logcat, I got the following log:

```
> 05/11 16:18:25.453 10380 10392 Info Unity MemoryManager: Using
> 'Dynamic Heap' Allocator. 05/11 16:18:25.505 10380 10392 Info Unity
> SystemInfo CPU = ARMv7 VFPv3 NEON, Cores = 4, Memory = 1859mb 05/11
> 16:18:25.506 10380 10392 Info Unity SystemInfo ARM big.LITTLE
> configuration: 4 big (mask: 0xf), 0 little (mask: 0x0) 05/11
> 16:18:25.507 10380 10392 Info Unity ApplicationInfo
> com.DynastyOfGames.FactoryTime version 0.3 build
> 230834fe-f050-49c9-81f7-475c656f2f51 05/11 16:18:25.507 10380 10392
> Info Unity Built from '2019.4/release' branch, Version '2019.4.20f1
> (6dd1c08eedfa)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU
> 'armeabi-v7a', Stripping 'Enabled' 05/11 16:18:25.857 10380 10392
> Debug Unity  GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture GL_AMD_performance_monitor
> GL_AMD_program_binary_Z400 GL_EXT_debug_label GL_EXT_debug_marker
> GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer GL_EXT_robustness
> GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV
> GL_NV_fence GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_depth_texture
> GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_sync
> GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_element_index_uint
> GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap GL_OES_fragment_precision_high
> GL_OES_get_program_binary GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil
> GL_OES_depth_texture_cube_map GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8
> GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_texture_3D GL_OES_texture_float
> GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear
> GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_vertex_half_float
> GL_OES_vertex_type_10_10_10_2 GL_OES_vertex_array_object
> GL_QCOM_alpha_test GL_QCOM_binning_control GL_QCOM_driver_control
> GL_QCOM_perfmon_global_mode GL_QCOM_extended_get GL_QCOM_extended_get2
> GL_QCOM_tiled_rendering GL_QCOM_writeonly_rendering GL_EXT_sRGB
> GL_EXT_sRGB_write_control GL_EXT 05/11 16:18:25.857 10380 10392 Debug
> Unity _texture_sRGB_decode GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic
> GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture GL_EXT_color_buffer_float
> GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_EXT_disjoint_timer_query 05/11
> 16:18:31.829 10380 10430 Warn Unity The referenced script on this
> Behaviour (Game Object 'Main Camera') is missing!  05/11 16:18:31.829
> 10380 10430 Warn Unity (Filename:  Line: 334) 05/11 16:18:31.829 10380
> 10430 Warn Unity  05/11 16:18:31.829 10380 10430 Warn Unity The
> referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object 'Main Camera') is
> missing!  05/11 16:18:31.829 10380 10430 Warn Unity (Filename:  Line:
> 334) 05/11 16:18:31.829 10380 10430 Warn Unity  05/11 16:18:31.843
> 10380 10430 Warn Unity The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game
> Object 'Игра') is missing!  05/11 16:18:31.843 10380 10430 Warn Unity
> (Filename:  Line: 334) 05/11 16:18:31.843 10380 10430 Warn Unity 
> 05/11 16:18:31.909 10380 10392 Info Unity Starting Auth with token
> client. 05/11 16:18:31.909 10380 10392 Info Unity
> UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object) 05/11 16:18:31.909 10380 10392
> Info Unity GooglePlayGames.Android.AndroidClient:Authenticate(Boolean,
> Action`1) 05/11 16:18:31.909 10380 10392 Info Unity   05/11
> 16:18:31.909 10380 10392 Info Unity (Filename:
> ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35) 05/11 16:18:31.909
> 10380 10392 Info Unity  05/11 16:18:31.966 10380 10392 Info Unity
> Starting Auth with token client. 05/11 16:18:31.966 10380 10392 Info
> Unity UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object) 05/11 16:18:31.966 10380
> 10392 Info Unity
> GooglePlayGames.Android.AndroidClient:Authenticate(Boolean, Action`1)
> 05/11 16:18:31.966 10380 10392 Info Unity UIscript:Start() 05/11
> 16:18:31.966 10380 10392 Info Unity   05/11 16:18:31.966 10380 10392
> Info Unity (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line:
> 35) 05/11 16:18:31.966 10380 10392 Info Unity  05/11 16:18:31.967
> 10380 10392 Info Unity Starting Auth with token client. 05/11
> 16:18:31.967 10380 10392 Info Unity UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType,
> Object) 05/11 16:18:31.967 10380 10392 Info Unity
> GooglePlayGames.Android.AndroidClient:Authenticate(Boolean, Action`1)
> 05/11 16:18:31.967 10380 10392 Info Unity Auntification:Start() 05/11
> 16:18:31.967 10380 10392 Info Unity   05/11 16:18:31.967 10380 10392
> Info Unity (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line:
> 35) 05/11 16:18:31.967 10380 10392 Info Unity  05/11 16:18:32.035
> 10380 10392 Info Unity Returning an error code. 05/11 16:18:32.035
> 10380 10392 Info Unity UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object) 05/11
> 16:18:32.035 10380 10392 Info Unity
> GooglePlayGames.Android.<>c__DisplayClass18_0:<Authenticate>b__0(Int32)
> 05/11 16:18:32.035 10380 10392 Info Unity System.Action`1:Invoke(T)
> 05/11 16:18:32.035 10380 10392 Info Unity System.Action`1:Invoke(T)
> 05/11 16:18:32.035 10380 10392 Info Unity
> System.Reflection.MonoMethod:Invoke(Object, BindingFlags, Binder,
> Object[], CultureInfo) 05/11 16:18:32.035 10380 10392 Info Unity
> System.Reflection.MethodBase:Invoke(Object, Object[]) 05/11
> 16:18:32.035 10380 10392 Info Unity
> UnityEngine.AndroidJavaProxy:Invoke(String, Object[]) 05/11
> 16:18:32.035 10380 10392 Info Unity
> UnityEngine._AndroidJNIHelper:InvokeJavaProxyMethod(AndroidJavaProxy,
> IntPtr, IntPtr) 05/11 16:18:32.035 10380 10392 Info Unity   05/11
> 16:18:32.035 10380 10392 Info Unity (Filename:
> ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35) 05/11 16:18:32.035
> 10380 10392 Info Unity  05/11 16:18:32.056 10380 10392 Warn Unity !!!
> [Play Games Plugin 0.10.12] 05/11/21 16:18:32 +05:00 WARNING:
> PlayGamesPlatform already initialized. Ignoring this call. 05/11
> 16:18:32.056 10380 10392 Warn Unity UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType,
> Object) 05/11 16:18:32.056 10380 10392 Warn Unity
> System.Action:Invoke() 05/11 16:18:32.056 10380 10392 Warn Unity
> GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.PlayGamesHelperObject:Update() 05/11
> 16:18:32.056 10380 10392 Warn Unity   05/11 16:18:32.056 10380 10392
> Warn Unity (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line:
> 35) 05/11 16:18:32.056 10380 10392 Warn Unity  05/11 16:18:32.057
> 10380 10392 Info Unity  [Play Games Plugin 0.10.12] 05/11/21 16:18:32
> +05:00 DEBUG: Activating PlayGamesPlatform. 05/11 16:18:32.057 10380 10392 Info Unity UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object) 05/11
> 16:18:32.057 10380 10392 Info Unity System.Action:Invoke() 05/11
> 16:18:32.057 10380 10392 Info Unity
> GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.PlayGamesHelperObject:Update() 05/11
> 16:18:32.057 10380 10392 Info Unity   05/11 16:18:32.057 10380 10392
> Info Unity (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line:
> 35) 05/11 16:18:32.057 10380 10392 Info Unity  05/11 16:18:32.058
> 10380 10392 Info Unity  [Play Games Plugin 0.10.12] 05/11/21 16:18:32
> +05:00 DEBUG: PlayGamesPlatform activated: GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform 05/11 16:18:32.058 10380 10392 Info
> Unity UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object) 05/11 16:18:32.058 10380
> 10392 Info Unity System.Action:Invoke() 05/11 16:18:32.058 10380 10392
> Info Unity GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.PlayGamesHelperObject:Update()
> 05/11 16:18:32.058 10380 10392 Info Unity   05/11 16:18:32.058 10380
> 10392 Info Unity (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h
> Line: 35) 05/11 16:18:32.058 10380 10392 Info Unity  05/11
> 16:18:32.059 10380 10392 Info Unity Returning an error code. 05/11
> 16:18:32.059 10380 10392 Info Unity UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType,
> Object) 05/11 16:18:32.059 10380 10392 Info Unity
> GooglePlayGames.Android.<>c__DisplayClass18_0:<Authenticate>b__0(Int32)
> 05/11 16:18:32.059 10380 10392 Info Unity System.Action`1:Invoke(T)
> 05/11 16:18:32.059 10380 10392 Info Unity System.Action`1:Invoke(T)
> 05/11 16:18:32.059 10380 10392 Info Unity
> System.Reflection.MonoMethod:Invoke(Object, BindingFlags, Binder,
> Object[], CultureInfo) 05/11 16:18:32.059 10380 10392 Info Unity
> System.Reflection.MethodBase:Invoke(Object, Object[]) 05/11
> 16:18:32.059 10380 10392 Info Unity
> UnityEngine.AndroidJavaProxy:Invoke(String, Object[]) 05/11
> 16:18:32.059 10380 10392 Info Unity
> UnityEngine._AndroidJNIHelper:InvokeJavaProxyMethod(AndroidJavaProxy,
> IntPtr, IntPtr) 05/11 16:18:32.059 10380 10392 Info Unity   05/11
> 16:18:32.059 10380 10392 Info Unity (Filename:
> ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35) 05/11 16:18:32.059
> 10380 10392 Info Unity  05/11 16:18:32.342 10380 10392 Info Unity Oh
> no 05/11 16:18:32.342 10380 10392 Info Unity
> UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object) 05/11 16:18:32.342 10380 10392
> Info Unity System.Action`1:Invoke(T) 05/11 16:18:32.342 10380 10392
> Info Unity System.Action`2:Invoke(T1, T2) 05/11 16:18:32.342 10380
> 10392 Info Unity
> GooglePlayGames.<>c__DisplayClass33_0:<Authenticate>b__0(SignInStatus)
> 05/11 16:18:32.342 10380 10392 Info Unity System.Action`1:Invoke(T)
> 05/11 16:18:32.342 10380 10392 Info Unity System.Action`1:Invoke(T)
> 05/11 16:18:32.342 10380 10392 Info Unity System.Action:Invoke() 05/11
> 16:18:32.342 10380 10392 Info Unity
> GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.PlayGamesHelperObject:Update() 05/11
> 16:18:32.342 10380 10392 Info Unity   05/11 16:18:32.342 10380 10392
> Info Unity (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line:
> 35) 05/11 16:18:32.342 10380 10392 Info Unity  05/11 16:18:32.358
> 10380 10392 Info Unity  [Play Games Plugin 0.10.12] 05/11/21 16:18:32
> +05:00 DEBUG: Authentication failed - developer error 05/11 16:18:32.358 10380 10392 Info Unity UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType,
> Object) 05/11 16:18:32.358 10380 10392 Info Unity
> System.Action:Invoke() 05/11 16:18:32.358 10380 10392 Info Unity
> GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.PlayGamesHelperObject:Update() 05/11
> 16:18:32.358 10380 10392 Info Unity   05/11 16:18:32.358 10380 10392
> Info Unity (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line:
> 35) 05/11 16:18:32.358 10380 10392 Info Unity  05/11 16:18:32.359
> 10380 10392 Info Unity  [Play Games Plugin 0.10.12] 05/11/21 16:18:32
> +05:00 DEBUG: Authentication failed - developer error 05/11 16:18:32.359 10380 10392 Info Unity UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType,
> Object) 05/11 16:18:32.359 10380 10392 Info Unity
> System.Action:Invoke() 05/11 16:18:32.359 10380 10392 Info Unity
> GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.PlayGamesHelperObject:Update() 05/11
> 16:18:32.359 10380 10392 Info Unity   05/11 16:18:32.359 10380 10392
> Info Unity (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line:
> 35) 05/11 16:18:32.359 10380 10392 Info Unity  05/11 16:18:34.536
> 10380 10380 Info Unity Returning an error code. 05/11 16:18:34.536
> 10380 10380 Info Unity UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object) 05/11
> 16:18:34.536 10380 10380 Info Unity
> GooglePlayGames.Android.<>c__DisplayClass18_0:<Authenticate>b__0(Int32)
> 05/11 16:18:34.536 10380 10380 Info Unity System.Action`1:Invoke(T)
> 05/11 16:18:34.536 10380 10380 Info Unity System.Action`1:Invoke(T)
> 05/11 16:18:34.536 10380 10380 Info Unity
> System.Reflection.MonoMethod:Invoke(Object, BindingFlags, Binder,
> Object[], CultureInfo) 05/11 16:18:34.536 10380 10380 Info Unity
> System.Reflection.MethodBase:Invoke(Object, Object[]) 05/11
> 16:18:34.536 10380 10380 Info Unity
> UnityEngine.AndroidJavaProxy:Invoke(String, Object[]) 05/11
> 16:18:34.536 10380 10380 Info Unity
> UnityEngine._AndroidJNIHelper:InvokeJavaProxyMethod(AndroidJavaProxy,
> IntPtr, IntPtr) 05/11 16:18:34.536 10380 10380 Info Unity   05/11
> 16:18:34.536 10380 10380 Info Unity (Filename:
> ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35) 05/11 16:18:34.536
> 10380 10380 Info Unity  05/11 16:18:34.561 10380 10392 Info Unity Oh
> no! 05/11 16:18:34.561 10380 10392 Info Unity
> UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object) 05/11 16:18:34.561 10380 10392
> Info Unity System.Action`1:Invoke(T) 05/11 16:18:34.561 10380 10392
> Info Unity System.Action`2:Invoke(T1, T2) 05/11 16:18:34.561 10380
> 10392 Info Unity
> GooglePlayGames.<>c__DisplayClass33_0:<Authenticate>b__0(SignInStatus)
> 05/11 16:18:34.561 10380 10392 Info Unity System.Action`1:Invoke(T)
> 05/11 16:18:34.561 10380 10392 Info Unity System.Action`1:Invoke(T)
> 05/11 16:18:34.561 10380 10392 Info Unity System.Action:Invoke() 05/11
> 16:18:34.561 10380 10392 Info Unity
> GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.PlayGamesHelperObject:Update() 05/11
> 16:18:34.561 10380 10392 Info Unity   05/11 16:18:34.561 10380 10392
> Info Unity (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line:
> 35) 05/11 16:18:34.561 10380 10392 Info Unity  05/11 16:18:34.576
> 10380 10392 Info Unity  [Play Games Plugin 0.10.12] 05/11/21 16:18:34
> +05:00 DEBUG: Authentication canceled 05/11 16:18:34.576 10380 10392 Info Unity UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object) 05/11 16:18:34.576
> 10380 10392 Info Unity System.Action:Invoke() 05/11 16:18:34.576 10380
> 10392 Info Unity
> GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.PlayGamesHelperObject:Update() 05/11
> 16:18:34.576 10380 10392 Info Unity   05/11 16:18:34.576 10380 10392
> Info Unity (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line:
> 35) 05/11 16:18:34.576 10380 10392 Info Unity
```

The only thing that the eye could catch on to was the above-described "authentication failed - developer error" error. I ask your mercy, and I keep hope that there will be people who will help.